# Request location in android

Tags: java, android

I have this code to request someones location in Android, can someone explain to me why it isnt working, After the location request it sets two EditText fields as he latitude and Longitude values

```
package com.datapost.location;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
        onStart();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            EditText mLatitudeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lat);
            EditText mLongitudeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lon);
            String s = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
            String f = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            mLatitudeText.setText(s);
            mLongitudeText.setText(f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        connectionResult.getErrorCode();
        return;
    }

}
```

I dont know why it wont work, tried everything seems like a basicjob to do however it just does not want to work, do I have to have an API key or something, do I need one just to get a persons location from their phone.
Any help appreciated with this

I can also post the error mess message I got

Error

```
06-13 15:54:56.311 11320-11320/com.datapost.location W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.datapost.location-1/lib/x86_64
06-13 15:54:56.339 11320-11320/com.datapost.location I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
06-13 15:54:56.906 11320-11320/com.datapost.location W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-13 15:54:57.032 11320-11366/com.datapost.location D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                       [ 06-13 15:54:57.041 11320:11320 D/         ]
                                                                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f6d81a1a480, tid 11320


                                                                       [ 06-13 15:54:57.093 11320:11366 D/         ]
                                                                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f6d85b50840, tid 11366
06-13 15:54:57.109 11320-11366/com.datapost.location I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
```

I changed the code to this for that If statement

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            EditText mLatitudeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lat);
            EditText mLongitudeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lon);
            String s = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
            String f = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            mLatitudeText.setText(s);
            mLongitudeText.setText(f);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you running this on Android 6.0?? If yes, you have to manage permission at runtime. Also post error logs if you're getting any.

Comment: There is no output onto the EditText fields which is why I am confused,  will add error Log now...

Comment: I am using android 6.0

Comment: that errror post is from logcat

Comment: Refer this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: But didnt I already check the permission as I needed it in the public void onConnected method, unless something wrong with it let me see...

Comment: Your check is wrong. If your `if` statement evaluates to true (i.e. permission granted) you return from the function so the code fetching the location is never executed. And if your `if` statement evaluates to false, you fetch the location but it won't work as the permissions are nor granted.

Comment: changed the code as above no result though

Comment: I really don know what I am doing wrong

Comment: @AndrewBarker,First you check Version of operating system this than add permission. you Request location permisson every. you need to add one time permission in app..

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable geoLocation API from your google console and create a key and use that key in your app menifest like this :

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

also check for runtime permission for android M+